# Ember : classNameBinding for a component - class is added, but CSS transition is skipped

Tags: ember.js, components

Ember (*latest*) classNameBinding for a component - class is added on `didInsertElement()`, but CSS transition is seemingly skipped.

When I add and remove the class in dev tools or comment out the loaded class in the stylesheet the animation occurs, but otherwise - when the element is inserted it just goes from *0 to 100* immediately.

Here is a full example in [an ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/42a2f8950cc54ff1f601f92276b324ba?fileTreeShown=false&numColumns=2&openFiles=components.example-component.js%2Cstyles.app.css)

### example-component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'section',
  classNames: ['example-component'],
  classNameBindings: ['loaded'],
  
  loaded: false,
  
  didInsertElement() {
    this.set('loaded', true);
  },
});
```

### CSS

```
.example-component {      
  opacity: .1; /* so you can see it */
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
  transition: 3s;
}

.example-component.loaded {
    opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set `loaded` property in the separate run loop.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_schedule

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'section',
  classNames: ['example-component'],
  classNameBindings: ['loaded'],

  loaded: false,

  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    Ember.run.next(this, function () {
      this.set('loaded', true);
    });
  },
});
```